# code improvement for multiple submissions in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some unreliable code that I'm trying to see if I can improve, a user can answer questions that are assigned to them. The answer text field is populated by iterating over the questions assigned to them, and the code looks like this:

```
<%= form_for answer do |f| %>
  <% current_user.all_weekly_questions.each do |question| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'questions[][id]', question.id %>
      <h4><%= question.name %></h4>
      <% if question.text_based? %>
        <%= text_area_tag 'questions[][reply]', nil, class: 'form-control', "required" => true, rows: 2 %>
      <% else %>
        <% (question.min_number_range..question.max_number_range).each do |question_value| %>
          <%= label_tag "questions[][reply]", class: 'question-value-label' do %>
            <%= question_value %>
            <%= radio_button_tag "questions[][reply]", "#{question_value}" %>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

now already here I see some issues, as there is no way for me to really validate if they answer all their questions, because I just iterate over them and populate an answer form.

Now, in my controller I have:

```
  def new
    @user = User.eager_load(:questions, :group_questions)
                .find(current_user.id)
    @user_answered_weekly_questions =
      current_user.answers.includes(user: [:answers])
      .detect { |a| a.week_number == @current_week.to_s }
      .present?
    @answer = current_user.answers.new
    @current_week = Time.zone.now.strftime('%V')
  end

  def create
    @questions = current_user.questions
    params[:questions].map do |question|
      current_user.answers.create(
        question_id: question[:id],
        reply:       question[:reply],
        week_number: Time.zone.now.strftime('%V')
      )
    end
    redirect_to answers_path
  end
```

here I also spot some issues, which is in the create. I don't really have a conditional that checks if it's saved or not. Thus it becomes problematic.

Now the last issue I'm having is that, due to the nature of how I populate my form if I have 2 questions that are number based, I generate a set of `radio_button_tag`, and it has no way of telling that they are different group - so a user is unable to answer both questions.

Now what I'd like to improve / fix is:

- Form code so it's more stable
- Issue where I can't have 2 questions that are number based (radio buttons doesn't know that they are different groups because the value on both of them are `questions[][reply]`
- Improve create action in my controller so it just doesn't run.
- detect if a user haven't answered all their questions

Schema:

```
  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "company_id"
    t.boolean  "optional",         default: false
    t.boolean  "active",           default: true
    t.datetime "created_at",                       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                       null: false
    t.integer  "frequency",        default: 0
    t.integer  "answer_format",    default: 0
    t.integer  "min_number_range"
    t.integer  "max_number_range"
  end


  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "reply"
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "week_number"
  end
```

Comment: Could you show schema.rb part for questions and answers?

Comment: @weezing updated :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### It's all about the models.

I would start by reviewing your domain models - you are obviously missing a component which groups a bunch of Questions together.

We also need to deal with one pretty obvious issue in any Q/A or polling app. We need to separate between the questions and answers on the form and user feedback.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questionnaires
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  week_number :integer
#
class Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
  has_many :user_questionnaires, class_name: 'Users::Questionnaire'
  scope :this_week, -> { where(week_number:  Time.zone.now.strftime('%V')) 
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: answers
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  question_id :integer
#  body        :string
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: questions
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  questionnaire_id :integer
#  body             :string
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :questionnaire
  has_many :answers
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

This provides a pretty natural hierarchy - Questionnaires have many Questions, which have many potential Answers.

These could be created by administrators on a admin GUI for example.

In your domain modeling you have a spattering of metadata across your Question and Answer models - I would consider carefully if these models really need to know anything more than their value / text and who they immediately belong to. If you need to add data - add it to the questionnaire so you are not stuffing duplicate data all over your tables.

We are not finished with the modeling quite yet. Instead of bloating your Question / Answer models with the problems of dealing with user replies you will want to create a separate models for that purpose:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users_answers
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  users_questionnaire_id :integer
#  question_id            :integer
#  answer_id              :integer
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#
class Users::Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users_questionnaire, class_name: 'Users::Questionnaire',
                                   inverse_of: :users_replies
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :answer
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users_questionnaires
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id          :integer
#  questionnaire_id :integer
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#
class Users::Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :questionnaire
  has_many :users_replies, class_name: 'Users::Reply'
  delegate :questions, to: :questionnaire
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_replies
end
```

### Putting the models to use:

```
class Users::QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @questionnaires = current_user.questionnaires
  end

  def new
    @questionnaire = current_user.questionnaires.new(
      # We need to tell ruby to use the "root" namespace
      questionnaire: ::Questionnaire.this_week.first!
    )
    # @todo - handle case where no weekly questionnaire is found
  end

  def create
    @questionnaire = current_user.questionnaires.new(create_params)
    if @questionnaire.save
      redirect_to :index
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  private

    def create_params
      params.require(:questionnaire)
            .permit(
                :questionnaire_id,
                users_replies: [:question_id, :answer_id]
            )
    end

end
```

The controller is pretty straight forward - we create a `Users::Questionaire` in memory in `#new`, and accept user input and persist a `Users::Questionaire` and the related models in `#create`.

We can simplify the form greatly by using `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_for @questionnaire do |f| %>

  <% f.object.questions.each do |q| %>
    <fieldset>
      <%= f.fields_for :users_answers, Users::Answer.new(question_id: q.id) do |a| %>
        <%= a.hidden_field(:question_id) %>
        <%= a.collection_radio_buttons(:answer_id, q.answers, :id, :body) %>
      <% end %>
      <legend><%= q.body %></legend>
    </fieldset>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

### What about validation?

```
class Users::Questionnaire < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :questionnaire
  has_many :users_answers, class_name: 'Users::Answer'
  delegate :questions, to: :questionnaire
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users_answers

  validate :number_of_answers

  def number_of_answers
    unless users_answers.size == questions.size
      errors[:users_answers] << "You have not answered all the questions"
    end
  end
end
```

This is pretty simplified version of validating the user input. To create a more complex validation if you for example wanted to add a error for each missing answer or ensure that the answer is valid the best way is by creating a [custom validator class](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators). Just don't fall in the trap of doing everything in your controllers.

### Notes

- If you are always dealing with simple numerical answers ("Rate this X from 1 to 10") you can simplify by omitting the Answer model / relation.

### Added

I forgot to mention that you need to add a relationship between users and `Users::Questionnaire`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_many :questionnaires, class_name: 'Users::Questionnaire'
end
```

Setting up the routes is pretty straight forward:

```
namespace :users
  resources :questionnaires, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Using a namespace for the controller is optional and it really depends on what routes you want for the app.

Comment: Hi Max, a very nice and detailed reply. I'm working on trying your suggestions now. Can you show me a potential setup for this on routes?

Comment: also running into early issues with undefined method questionnaires for user etc.

Comment: Also, my questions are set on a set interval so it's not a standard polling app. Admin adds questions to be weekly, biweekly, monthly or quarterly. I feel this makes the code with the questionnaire quite far off from what I have currently