# Making a conditionnal form using Rails & Stimulus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, stimulusjs

I'm a newbie in computer development, I have started using Ruby on Rails framework with Stimulus to add some dynamic elements to my pages.

**Context**

I am working on a video game recommendation system, to do so the player will have to answer a detailled list of questions.
To be as pertinent as possible, I would like to make some conditional questions.

Example : You answer "B" to question 1, the next question is 1-B
You answer "A" to question 1, the next question is 1-A, and so on.

**How to do it**

After some research, it seems that the best practice to do so would be to have a massive form with every input and to show/hide the ones depending of the values.

1. Player gives input B to the question 1
2. I check the value of the question 1 input
3. If the value is A, I show the question 1-A
4. If the value is B ...

**The problem**

So far, I managed to get to the point 3. but with some issues.

When I'm using the simple_form :collection attributes which gives a drop-down menu, I manage to access the input value in the list using the Stimulus target "input".

[The not-so working version with a collection:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kohRL.png)

However, if I change the input type to "radio_boxes" I can only access the first value in the collection.

[The not working version with a radio_buttons type for the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6TCq.png)

I guess my problem is located in the JS controller, would be awesome if you had any idea regarding this issue!

**My code**

I have two tables, a player and a personnality which belongs to a player :

```
Player model:

class Player < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, uniqueness: true

  has_one :personality, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personality
end

Personnality model: 

class Personality < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :player
  validates :player, uniqueness: true

  SATURDAY_NIGHT_QUESTION = "It's Saturday night, you are probably"
  SATURDAY_NIGHT_ANSWERS = [
    "Staying at home",
    "Going out"
  ]

  SATURDAY_HOME_QUESTION = "Alright, comfy Saturday at home sounds good!, what do you do there?"
  SATURDAY_OUT_QUESTION = "Alright, party time then! Where are we headed to?"

  SATURDAY_HOME_ANSWERS = [
    "Reading a book",
    "Playing online with some friends"
  ]

  SATURDAY_OUT_ANSWERS = [
    "Going to a bar of course",
    "A friend is having a boardgame session"
  ]

end
```

I have put my questions & answers in my models to centralize it, in case I will have to edit it afterwards (is it a good idea by the way to put it in the model?).

View

```
<p>Welcome, player</p>
<div data-controller="sample-dropdown">
  <%= simple_form_for(@player) do |f| %>
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :personality do |p| %>
      <% p.input :player_id, as: :hidden, input_html: { id: p.object.player_id }%>
      <%= p.input :saturday_night, label: Personality::SATURDAY_NIGHT_QUESTION,
      collection: Personality::SATURDAY_NIGHT_ANSWERS, as: :radio_buttons,
      input_html: {data:{target: 'sample-dropdown.input', action:'input->sample-dropdown#answer'}} %>
      <div class="disable" data-sample-dropdown-target="test1">
        <%= p.input :saturday_action, label: Personality::SATURDAY_HOME_QUESTION, collection: Personality::SATURDAY_HOME_ANSWERS, include_blank: false %>
      </div>
      <div class="disable" data-sample-dropdown-target="test2">
        <%= p.input :saturday_action, label: Personality::SATURDAY_OUT_QUESTION, collection: Personality::SATURDAY_OUT_ANSWERS, include_blank: false %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  <% end %>
  <% console %>
</div>
```

I am using the [simple form gem](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form/wiki) with [Stimulus](https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/) a small JS framework.

Here is my JS Controller :

```
mport { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

// Connects to data-controller="sample-dropdown"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["input", "test1", "test2"]

  connect() {
    console.log(this.inputTarget)
  }

  answer() {
    const element = this.inputTarget
    console.log(element.value)

    switch (element.value) {
      case "Staying at home":
        this.test1Target.classList.remove("disable")
        this.test1Target.classList.add("active")
        this.test2Target.classList.remove("active")
        this.test2Target.classList.add("disable")
      case "Going out":
        this.test2Target.classList.remove("disable")
        this.test2Target.classList.add("active")
        this.test1Target.classList.remove("active")
        this.test1Target.classList.add("disable")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're really making one huge cardinal sin right out of the gate here. By adding all those questions as constants in the Personality model you're coding your data into the application instead of actually thinking like a programmer and creating objects that encapsulate the data. You should start thinking in terms of question and answer models and how you would link them together.

Comment: Hello Max, thanks for your quick feedback!
To be honest, I did not thought about making a dedicated model for my questions as well.
It would however clarify huge parts of my actual code.

Comment: Basically what you're building here is yet another questionaire - this is hardly breaking new ground and you might to search for existing examples / tutorials. You'll typically learn more by analyzing how other people solved similiar problems instead of making everything up on your own.

Comment: This is a pretty long answer a wrote to a similiar question many years ago but is still pretty relevant - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589491/544825

Comment: I followed up your initial answer, my DB is looking way better now, thanks! 
One quick follow-up question if I may, 
I intend to have a "score" for each player, meaning that if their answer for the 1) question is B, I will add X in a dedicated column of my player_profile model.
I started adding this logic in my player_profile model, is it the right place to do so?
I wanted to avoid putting logical elements into the controller, so seemed the right place.
Thanks!